# How to remove column headers from listview in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to remove column headers in ASP.NET list view control?

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" class="lv" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
            onprerender="ListView1_PreRender" 
            onselectedindexchanged="ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
            style="text-align: left">
```

Comment: Do you use C# or VB.NET  ?

Comment: Did you try using an ItemTemplate and not having a header row?

Answer (score 1):

Using a LayoutTemplate you can define the column and then hide specific columns using the OnLayoutCreated event.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" class="lv" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        onprerender="ListView1_PreRender" 
        onselectedindexchanged="ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
        style="text-align: left" OnLayoutCreated="OnLayoutCreated">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer">
            <tr>
                <td><asp:Label id="columnToHide" runat="server" Text="Column 1" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%#Eval("name")></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

And then in the code-behind:

```
protected void OnLayoutCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ListView1.FindControl("columnToHide").Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: The question is about ASP.NET, not Windows Forms.

Comment: @MichaelLiu My apologies, have updated my post with relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an ItemTemplate and don't define a header row in the LayoutTemplate.

Link to ListView web server control overview:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx)

Link to ListView web server control class definition and examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<asp:Listview id="listview1" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqldatasource1">
    <LayoutTemplate>
                    <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer">
                        <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder">
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <asp:HyperLink runat="server" text='<%#Eval("name")>'></asp:HyperLink>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>


    </asp:Listview>
```